# Infinite group with no maximal normal solvable subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups, normal-subgroups

If $G$ is a finite group, then it has a maximal solvable normal subgroup. I think that this fails for infinite groups, but I don't know an example. Can you name one?

Comment: Are you looking for that example in non-abelian groups?

Comment: If the group were abelian, it would be its own, unique, maximal, normal, solvable subgroup - so I am not expecting a counterexample there. More precisely, the group must certainly not be solvable.

Comment: In fact, I know that if $G$ is divisible so it has no any maximal subgroup. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Note that I do not require the subgroup to be proper; if $G$ is solvable, it satisfies all conditions because $G$ is a subgroup of itself. It is also clearly maximal with these properties.

Comment: Take the union of any infinite ascending chain of finite soluble groups of unbounded derived length. For example, start with a cyclic group, and keep taking wreath products and embedding each one in the next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the group $U$ of upper triangular infinite (in the bottom-right direction) matrices with real coefficients (or coefficients from your favorite commutative ring), with all $1$'s on diagonal so that all but finitely many off-diagonal values are zero:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & a_{12} & a_{13} & \ldots\\
0 & 1      & a_{23} & \ldots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\end{array}\right]  
$$
 This will give you an example: To see an increasing chain of normal solvable subgroups (of derived length increasing to infinity), consider first the abelian subgroup $N_1<U$, where the only nonzero off-diagonal entries occur in the 1st row. It is easy to see that $N_1$ is normal in $U$. Next, conider the subgroup $N_2$ consisting of matrices where the only nonzero off-diagonal entries occur in the first two rows, and so on. The subgroup $N_n$ thus constructed will have derived length $n$ and $N_n$ is normal in $U$. It is not hard to see that $U$ will not have a maximal solvable subgroup.

*What I do not know how to do is to construct a finitely-generated example with this property.* This looks like an interesting challenge, but is well beyond of what I can do.